# Statically linking Lua using Visual Studio 14

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, lua, linker, static-linking

I'm trying to link the latest Lua library with my x86 application using Visual Studio 14. I added the library under additional dependencies, and included the appropriate header files (`lua.hpp`, I also tried the manual `extern "C"` approach.) I'm compiling my module as a x86 binary and using the right Lua binaries (x86.) The error I get is the following:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "struct lua_State * __cdecl luaL_newstate(void)" (?luaL_newstate@@YAPAUlua_State@@XZ) referenced in function _DllMain@12
```

Obviously the header files have declared the `luaL_newstate` function, but looking at the supplied binary's (`lua53.lib`) symbols, it's quite clear that it doesn't actually supply any symbol named as such - instead it has one named `_luaL_newstate`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That one was compiled with the C++ compiler, note the decorated name.  You've got an extern "C" missing somewhere.

Comment: Yep, that was it, I had forgotten about some includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I had included the C headers (`lua.h`, `lauxlib.h` etc.) elsewhere. Removing those fixed my issue.